# Geotagging in xml can't be use in c#

Tags: c#, xml, twitter

I'm new in twitter api and now i try to get the geotagging from xml data of twitter

my code for get geo code is

```
XmlNode eNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("coordinates/georss:point");
```

error is

XPathException was unhandle by user code

-Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

but for other data suchas name, text or id is work fine to get it

thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It speaks the truth. Simply declare an `XmlNamespaceManager`, and tell it what uri "georss" refers to:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss");
```

and pass `ns` into the `SelectSingleNode` call:

```
XmlNode eNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("coordinates/georss:point", nsmgr);
```

You should be able to find the uri from the `xmlns` alias declaration at the top of the xml (edit: @dtb found it already).